# Button Counter not incrementing

Tags: javascript, html

I have been trying to keep count the number of times the button has been clicked. I have this code, In the first 4 labels it displays the assessment number entered. When clicked a second time it should display in the next 4 labels(5,6,7,8) but when i click the button a second time it doesn't increment the clicks variable and the assessment numbers entered in the textfield displays in the first 4 labels and not the second 4 labels. Why does the clicks variable not increment properly? What am i doing wrong?

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>JavaScript Form - Input Text Field</TITLE>


</HEAD>
<BODY>
<FORM NAME="test">
<H2>Enter something into the field and press the button. <br>
Please try this a few times.</H2>
<P>Assessment 1 <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="Assessment1" size ="5">
Assessment 2 <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="Assessment2" size ="5">
Assessment 3 <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="Assessment3" size ="5">
Assessment 4 <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="Assessment4" size ="5">

<INPUT TYPE="Button" Value="Add Module" name = "myButton" onClick="AddModule(this.form)">
</P>

<b>Assessment1:</b><label id="assessment1"> </label>
<b>Assessment2:</b><label id="assessment2"> </label>
<b>Assessment3:</b><label id="assessment3"> </label>
<b>Assessment4:</b><label id="assessment4"> </label>
<b>Total:</b><label id="total"></label>
</br>
<b>Assessment1:</b><label id="assessment5"> </label>
<b>Assessment2:</b><label id="assessment6"> </label>
<b>Assessment3:</b><label id="assessment7"> </label>
<b>Assessment4:</b><label id="assessment8"> </label>
<b>Total:</b><label id="assessment5"></label>

<SCRIPT Language="JavaScript">
<!--//
function AddModule(frm){
var clicks = 0;
if (frm.Assessment1.value == "" || frm.Assessment2.value == "" || frm.Assessment3.value == "" || frm.Assessment4.value == "")
  alert("You need to enter Assessment marks in all fields")
else{

clicks++;
window.document.test.myButton.value="Clicked " + clicks + " times";
  //alert("The field contains the text: " + frm.Assessment1.value)

  if (clicks ==1){
    var assessment1 = frm.Assessment1.value

    document.getElementById('assessment1').innerHTML = assessment1;
    frm.Assessment1.value = ""

    //alert("The field contains the text: " + frm.Assessment2.value)
    var assessment2 = frm.Assessment2.value

    document.getElementById('assessment2').innerHTML = assessment2;
    frm.Assessment2.value = ""

    //alert("The field contains the text: " + frm.Assessment3.value)
    var assessment3 = frm.Assessment3.value

    document.getElementById('assessment3').innerHTML = assessment3;
    frm.Assessment3.value = ""

    //alert("The field contains the text: " + frm.Assessment4.value)
    var assessment4 = frm.Assessment4.value

    document.getElementById('assessment4').innerHTML = assessment4;
    frm.Assessment4.value = ""


    var total = parseInt(assessment1) + parseInt(assessment2) + parseInt(assessment3) + parseInt(assessment4);
    total = total/4;

    document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = total;
}

  if (clicks ==2){
    var assessment5 = frm.Assessment1.value

    document.getElementById('assessment5').innerHTML = assessment5;
    frm.Assessment1.value = ""

    //alert("The field contains the text: " + frm.Assessment2.value)
    var assessment6 = frm.Assessment2.value

    document.getElementById('assessment6').innerHTML = assessment6;
    frm.Assessment2.value = ""

    //alert("The field contains the text: " + frm.Assessment3.value)
    var assessment7 = frm.Assessment3.value

    document.getElementById('assessment7').innerHTML = assessment7;
    frm.Assessment3.value = ""

    //alert("The field contains the text: " + frm.Assessment4.value)
    var assessment8 = frm.Assessment4.value

    document.getElementById('assessment8').innerHTML = assessment8;
    frm.Assessment4.value = ""

    clicks++;

    var total = parseInt(assessment5) + parseInt(assessment6) + parseInt(assessment7) + parseInt(assessment8);
    total = total/4;


    document.getElementById('assessment5').innerHTML = total;
}
 }

 }
 //-->
</SCRIPT>

</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put variable declaration outside of the function. Otherwise counter gets set to zero each time function is called and you are back where you started.

```
...
var clicks = 0;
function AddModule(frm){
...
```

Also, to debug situations similar to this, you should try to use built-in Development Tools (for most browsers you can open tools by hitting F12) of FireBug. Another option is to add `console.log(your_variable1, your_variable2, ...)` to see how the values are modified during script execution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move this line: `var clicks = 0;` outside your function, but still within your script tags.  As it is, each time you click the button and call the function it sets the clicks variable back to 0.

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lwalden/B7uja/